# Constraint for a many-to-many relationship table - both the related records need to reference the same dependent record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are three entities, `Student`, `Class` and  `Department`. Department and Student have a one-to-many relationship. Department and Class have a one-to-many relationship too. Student and Class have a many-to-many relationship.

```
create table Department 
(
    Id int primary key,
    -- ...
)

create table Student 
(
    Id int primary key, 
    DepartmentId int not null references Department(Id), 
    -- ....
)

create table Class 
(
    Id int primary key, 
    DepartmentId int not null references Department(Id), 
    ....
)
```

The following table is for the many-to-many relationship between Student and Class. Now user can put a pair of student/class which are from **different** (which shouldn't be allowed) departments in the table. Is it a way to prevent it besides using a trigger?

```
create table StudentAndClass 
(
    StudentId int references Student(Id), 
    ClassId int references Class(Id), 
    -- ....
    primary key (StudentId, ClassId)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without a trigger or special functions.  The idea is to use foreign key relationships . . . by defining an extra set of keys and adding `DepartmentId` (redundantly) to the junction table:

```
create table Students (
    StudentId int primary key, 
    DepartmentId int not null references Department(Id), 
    -- ....
    unique (DepartmentId, StudentId)
);

create table Classes (
    ClassId int primary key, 
    DepartmentId int not null references Department(Id), 
    ....
    unique (DepartmentId, ClassId)
);

create table StudentClasses (
    DepartmentId int references Department(DepartmentId),
    StudentId int, 
    ClassId int, 
    -- ....
    primary key (StudentId, ClassId),
    foreign key (DepartmentId, StudentId) references (DepartmentId, StudentId),
    foreign key (DepartmentId, ClassId) references (DepartmentId, ClassId),
);
```

You may not want the redundancy, but it is possible without triggers or special functions.

Comment: Very nice, just wondering up to which normal form it conforms? It seems there are two partial dependencies in `StudentClasses` table.

Comment: @ca9163d9 . . . I don't fully understand your comment.  I guess `DepartmentId` in the junction table technically violates normalization, but it is needed in order to have foreign keys express the actual relationship.

Comment: Yes, the junction table has two partial dependencies - `StudentId -> DepartmentId` and `ClassId -> DepartmentId`, (the PK is `(StudentId, ClassId)`). This will make it violates NF2. I'm wondering maybe trigger should be a better solution in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a CHECK CONSTRAINT

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckDepartment()
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN RETURN (
SELECT count(1)
    FROM StudentAndClass sc
    JOIN Student s on sc.StudentId=s.id
    JOIN Class c on sc.ClassId=c.id
WHERE c.DepartmentId<>s.DepartmentId
) END
go

ALTER TABLE StudentAndClass ADD CONSTRAINT chkDep CHECK (dbo.CheckDepartment() = 0);
```

This will guarantee that the departments will match