# Pros and Cons of Constraints across Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, rdbms, database-normalization

I have tables with relationships like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE DocumentType
(
   ID uniqueidentifier primary key,
   ...
)
GO

CREATE TABLE LinkedDoc
(
   ID uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
   DocumentTypeID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
   ...,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_LinkedDoc] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID, DocumentTypeID)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE LinkedDoc 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DocumentType_LinkedDoc 
        FOREIGN KEY(DocumentTypeID) REFERENCES DocumentType (ID)
GO

CREATE TABLE SomeOtherTable
(
   ID uniqueidentifier primary key,
   ...
)

CREATE TABLE ManyToMany 
(
   ID uniqueidentifier primary key,
   LinkedDocID uniqueidentifier,
   DocumentTypeID uniqueidentifier
   SomeOtherTableID uniqueidentifier,

   CONSTRAINT IX_ManyToMany UNIQUE (DocumentTypeID, SomeOtherTable)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE ManyToMany WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SomeOtherTable_ManyToMany 
      FOREIGN KEY (SomeOtherTableID) REFERENCES SomeOtherTable (ID)
GO

ALTER TABLE ManyToMany WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LinkedDoc_ManyToMany 
        FOREIGN KEY (LinkedDocID, DocumentTypeID) REFERENCES LinkedDoc (ID, DocumentTypeID)
GO
```

I omitted some details not relevant to my question. My goal was to build the tables so that each unique entity in the `SomeOtherTable` cannot be linked to more than one `LinkedDoc` with a given doc type. This is achieved above via the `IX_ManyToMany` constraint.

While it works, this solution isn't sitting well with me, and I'd like to change it now before I load data into the system. The main point of concern is `IX_ManyToMany` has a partial dependency on the tables primary key. Additionally `ID` in `LinkedDoc` is a `ROWGUIDCOL` meaning my pk for the table is not minimal.

Is there a better alternative? I'd be open to refactor my tables, but I would like to avoid db triggers and functions because at that point I feel like I'm putting business logic in the db. I prefer to keep BL in my API, where it's source controlled and easier to maintain.

I found this [Constraint for a many-to-many relationship table - both the related records need to reference the same dependent record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331719/constraint-for-a-many-to-many-relationship-table-both-the-related-records-need) The first answer is similar to my solution. The second uses a db function which I'm willing to consider, but would like to see if it can be done by modifying the schema. Although, rather than using the function solution I may opt to simply allow the db to violate my requirement and then handle it in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the standard way to go about this:

```sql
..
   CONSTRAINT IX_ManyToMany UNIQUE (DocumentTypeID, SomeOtherTable)
..
```

Note also that `ManyToMany` does not actually need a separate `ID` column, the PK can be made up of just `(LinkedDocID, SomeOtherTableID)`.

*The main point of concern is IX_ManyToMany has a partial dependency on the tables primary key. Additionally ID in LinkedDoc is a ROWGUIDCOL meaning my pk for the table is not minimal.*
I'm not sure why you are using `ROWGUIDCOL`, which is really for replication scenarios, but it's not relevant. Yes, it is sort-of a dependency, but you need to think of `LinkedDoc` as having *two* keys: a PK on `ID` and a secondary `UNIQUE` on `(ID, DocumentTypeID)`, and that extra column is just part of its secondary key which needs to go into the foreign table.

So the definition should be

```sql
CREATE TABLE LinkedDoc
(
   ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
   DocumentTypeID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
   ...,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_LinkedDoc] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID),
   INDEX UK_LinkedDoc_DocumentTypeID
       UNIQUE (ID, DocumentTypeID),
   CONSTRAINT FK_DocumentType_LinkedDoc
       FOREIGN KEY(DocumentTypeID) REFERENCES DocumentType (ID)
```

Note I have used a unique index rather than a unique constraint, as this allows you to add `INCLUDE`, and still works as a FK target.

---

The other option is to enforce this using an indexed view. This is unikely to be more efficient though, unless you need the indexed view anyway.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ManyToMany 
(
   LinkedDocID uniqueidentifier,
   SomeOtherTableID uniqueidentifier,
   PRIMARY KEY PK_ManyToMany (LinkedDocID, SomeOtherTableID),
   CONSTRAINT FK_SomeOtherTable_ManyToMany 
      FOREIGN KEY (SomeOtherTableID) REFERENCES SomeOtherTable (ID)
   CONSTRAINT FK_LinkedDoc_ManyToMany 
      FOREIGN KEY (LinkedDocID) REFERENCES LinkedDoc (ID)
)
```

Then create a joined view containing the `DocumentTypeID`

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.ManyToMany_DocumentTypeID
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  mm.LinkedDocID 
  mm.SomeOtherTableID,
  ld.DocumentTypeID
FROM dbo.ManyToMany mm
JOIN dbo.LinkedDoc ld ON ld.ID = mm.LinkedDocID;
```

And index it

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON ManyToMany_DocumentTypeID (SomeOtherTableID, DocumentTypeID);
```

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the view solution. Would it have any advantages beyond performance, such as avoiding anomalies when reading/modifying data?

Comment: No, because the foreign key also enforces it. The FK version is not subject to write anomalies (difference between the tables) in the same way as the view version, because the FK enforces that write anomalies cannot occur. I think the pros/cons basically comes down to: FK is more annoying for insertions/updates due to the extra column, view is less performant due to having to maintain a full indexed view index with a join.